# Error when running chrome on selenium remote node

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-grid, selenium-chromedriver

I have a selenium hub on one of my remote machines and other machines have selenium nodes.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Remote
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities

r = Remote('http://10.10.3.66:4444/wd/hub', DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
r.get(somewebsite)
```

`10.10.3.66` is the machine that has the hub on it, and I have a local node and a remote one.
Both connected to the remote hub, however chrome doesn't run on remote node but does in local.

I get the following exception when I run the code above (on remote node):

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u"unknown
>   error: Chrome failed to start: crashed\n  (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.12.301324
>   (de8ab311bc9374d0ade71f7c167bad61848c7c48),platform=Linux
>   2.6.32-042stab065.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)\nCommand duration or timeout: 60.05
>   seconds\nBuild info: version: '2.43.0', revision: '597b76b', time:
>   '2014-09-09 20:52:14'\nSystem info: host: 'linux-node-firefox', ip:
>   '10.10.3.67', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '2.6.32-042stab065.3', java.version: '1.6.0_33'\nDriver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver" ; Stacktrace:

And the following error appears on the node's console:

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.12.301324
>   (de8ab311bc9374d0ade71f7c167bad61848c7c48) on port 8719 Only local
>   connections are allowed. [0.011][WARNING]: PAC support disabled
>   because there is no system implementation

BTW, running the same code with `DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX` works.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you don't have the chrome driver on your machine. It can be downloaded from this link: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Add the following code to set the chrome driver path :

**Java**:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/.../chromedriver.exe");
```

**Python**:

```
chromedriver = "C:/.../chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
```

Arrange the path according to the location on you machine.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

1. Did You install chrome driver and set the PATH on the nodes ?